# Jenkins Multibranch Plugin & Remote API

Tags: json, api, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the 'new' Pipeline Multibranch Plugin with our Jenkins.
Since we want to test multiple branches this creates multiple subprojects for every branch. I always used the JSON API to get an overview of all the projects via https://myserver/api/json to write some tools for it and get the current build status. But with the new Multibranch plugin I just get the 'parent' job but none of the child 'jobs':

```
"jobs" : [

...

    {
      "_class" :  "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject",
      "name" : "-ProjectName-",
      "url" : "-ProjectURL-"
    },

...
```

Is there a way to 'expand' the Multibranch job in the remote API or another simple way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay - I solved it myself by adding ?depth=1